# `curveEaseInOut` is Unavailable in Swift 3

Tags: uiviewanimation, swift3, xcode8, ios10

In swift 3 update i am getting this error message [image]

kindly let me know if there is any change in method call.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use an array for `curveEaseInOut`:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, option: [.curveEaseIn, .curveEaseOut], animations: { [weak self]() -> void in }
```

The `curveEaseInOut` has been removed in `Swift 3.0`, so here is the workaround to achieve the animation.

Comment: do you have a reference for that change ?